# epoll_ctl : Operation not permitted error - c program

Tags: c, linux, file, io, epoll

```
  1 #include <sys/epoll.h>
  2 #include <stdio.h>
  3 #include <sys/types.h>
  4 #include <sys/stat.h>
  5 #include <fcntl.h>
  6 #include <string.h>
  7 #include <sys/uio.h>
  8 
  9 int main() {
 10   struct epoll_event event ;
 11   int ret,fd, epfd ;
 12 
 13   fd = open("doc", O_RDONLY);
 14   if( fd < 0 )
 15     perror("open");
 16 
 17   event.data.fd = fd ;
 18   event.events = EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT ;
 19 
 20   epfd = epoll_create(50);
 21   printf("%d", epfd );
 22 
 23   if( epfd < 0 )
 24     perror("epoll_create");
 25 
 26   ret = epoll_ctl( epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &event ) ;
 27   if( ret < 0 )
 28     perror("epoll_ctl");
 29 
 30 }
```

When compiling this code, there was no errors.
    gcc -o epoll epoo.c

but when i tried to execute the program 'epoll', i got the error message

> epoll_ctl:Operation not permitted.

I've tried to change the 'doc' file's mode to 0777 but it was not work.

What is the problem? Thank you :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From `epoll_ctl(2)`:

```
   EPERM  The target file fd does not support epoll.
```

I'm going to guess that `doc` is a regular file. Regular files are *always* ready for `read(2)` or `write(2)` operations, thus it doesn't make sense to `epoll(7)` or `select(2)` on regular files.

If `doc` is a pipe or unix domain socket, comment here (so I know to delete my post) and amend your question so others don't make the same mistake I did. :)

Comment: You were right! Doc is regular file. i'm a newby at programming so your answer was so helpful to me. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you're opening a regular file. `epoll()`, `select()`, and `poll()` don't make sense on regular files.

If it is a pipe or socket, then:

```
$mkfifo doc
```